# How to create attributed text in a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, swift, uicolor, nsmutableattributedstring

So I have a class:

```
class BoatTypeGame: UITableViewController
```

The table view has 14 rows. From rows 1-7, I want to make the color of the text `green` and for rows 8-14, I want to make the color of the text `red`. By the way, the cells will not have the same text every time the view loads; I used the `arc4random_uniform()` method to randomize the text. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to use attributed string in this case. Because you can change label color in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `tableViewWillDisplayCell` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or even `tableViewWillDisplayCell` just use a switch statement or an if statement.

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 1...7:
    println("row 1-7")
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
case 8...14:
    println("row 8-14")
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: Note: In swift you don't have to use `break` inside `case` statement that contains at least one expression.